# Integration question?

Tags: definite-integrals

[image]This question was asked in my exam. I couldn't solve it yet.

I tried with substituting $1-x^3 = u$ but couldn't solve it.

Comment: Maybe you were trying to write the following $$\int_{0}^1 \frac{(1-(1-x^3)^\sqrt2)^\sqrt3}{x^2}\; dx$$ if so, here's the code \int_{0}^1 \frac{(1-(1-x^3)^\sqrt2)^\sqrt3}{x^2}\; dx

Comment: Ugh. Are you sure this was the exam Q?...:)

Comment: Yes. This was the question.

Comment: What was the material taught in the course, immediately preceding the exam?

Comment: WolframAlpha gives a very complex expression if you are 12th grader surely this is not the question  that was given in the exam

Comment: A closed form solution can be written in terms of the Gamma function.  Are you familiar with the Gamma function?

Comment: I have not been taught Gamma function.